# doctorjs(aka jsctags) not work with vim+tagbar

Tags: javascript, vim, jsctags

I am using windows 7 64bit...

I've installed nodejs 0.6.11 by MSI installer, the installation path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs", it was automatically added to my %PATH% by the installer, I installed doctorjs by steps below:

1. I copied doctorjs files under "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\doctorjs"
2. I created jsctags.cmd filled with content copied from https://gist.github.com/1438882
3. I added following lines in my _vimrc:

let g:tagbar_type_javascript = {
    \ 'ctagsbin' : 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\jsctags.cmd'
\ }

The problem is, when I run jsctags.cmd "{My js folder}", it generates tags file with only content below:

!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   0   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Patrick Walton  /pwalton@mozilla.com/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  jsctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://github.com/pcwalton/jsctags  /GitHub repository/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   0.1 //

And when I run :tagbaropen in vim, it shows nothing for current js file..

Please kindly guide me where I did wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're getting some output, it looks like you have the gist implemented correctly.  But maybe your expectation of how to use it at a command line is different than the way it really works?

FYI: `jsctags.cmd "{my js folder}"` returns an empty tags file on my machine too. I don't think the command interface is very mature yet... so it looks like creating a tagfile of a whole folder is not possible - yet...

Try `jsctags.cmd "{file}"`. This should create a populated `tag` file.

Also note that tagbar calls jsctags like this: `jsctags -f - {file}`. This streams the output to stdout. So if you're debugging, try this form of the command.

As another debugging tip, modify your batchfile to output debugging info. ie:
Add lines like this:

```
echo "%~dp0"\"node.exe"  "D:\opt\node\doctorjs\bin\jsctags.js" %* > d:\debug.txt
```

Looking in `d:\debug.txt` will let you see what the command looks like as it is called from tagbar.

BTW: The gist you're using was mine...  I am wondering if I didn't test this batch file well enough with folders that have spaces in them.  Do some tests in both folders with and without spaces to see if there is a difference.  If you get more insight into where it works/doesn't, let me know and I can investigate further.

Comment: Thank you! darcyparker, I actually followed official Usage: "Simply go to your project root and invoke jsctags lib (replacing lib with the directory in which your JavaScript source files are stored). The tags file will be placed in the current directory." -- from https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs, it seems the official usage does not work.

Comment: And, now I am struggling into another error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
    at new Node (E:\Root\nodejs\doctorjs\narcissus\lib\parser.js:241:18)
    at idNode (E:\Root\nodejs\doctorjs\lib\cfa2\jscfa.js:211:11)
    at fixFun (E:\Root\nodejs\doctorjs\lib\cfa2\jscfa.js:333:13)
    at fixExp (E:\Root\nodejs\doctorjs\lib\cfa2\jscfa.js:296:5)
    at E:\Root\nodejs\doctorjs\lib\cfa2\jscfa.js:311:18
    ...

Answer (score 2):

Your issue might be related to the commit of narcissus you've cloned for doctorjs. Go into the narcissus folder in the doctorjs folder and run

```
git checkout 4ae5aff8b3
```

This should switch the head to the proper version of the file.